# Implementing additional encryption measures for Azure Key Vault Secrets

Tags: azure-keyvault

According to the [Microsoft Documentation on Key Vault Secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/about-secrets) :

> For highly sensitive data, clients should consider additional layers
> of protection for data. Encrypting data using a separate protection
> key prior to storage in Key Vault is one example.

There is no indication, however, of what such a scheme might look like.

In my scenario, every user with an account has a single unique secret which is being stored in the Key Vault and I would like to implement the recommended double encryption scheme.

I interpreted the documentation to imply that the ultimate solution might somehow include additional secrets being stored in the Key Vault, but perhaps I've misunderstood it.

Ultimately I'm looking for a sensible and security conscious way to encrypt the user's secret prior to being stored in the Key Vault.  I'm using Asp.Net Core Identity accounts.

Ideally, the solution would somehow be tied to the user's account credentials so that their secret can only be decrypted after they've successfully logged into the system.

Is there a recommended or "best practice" to handle this type of requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not specific because there are a lot of ways to achieve this goal.  One way would be to encrypt a user's secret using a certificate assigned to the user before storing the secret in the Key Vault.  If the certificate is on the user's local machine, then even if a malicious user were to somehow get into the Key Vault, the value of the secret would be useless.  Conversely, if a malicious user were to get the certificate, but not have the value stored in Key Vault, there still would not be a breach of the secure value.

The combination of a certificate on the local machine combined with an encrypted secret stored only in Key Vault would have a lot of security.